# python program to rename the file with current date in MMDDYYY format and send email with attachment

Tags: python, date, email, rename

Below is the program to send email with attachment:

I want to rename the file `student.xlsx` to `student_MMDDYYYY.xlsx` and send email with renamed file and after email is sent I want to delete that file. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
fromaddr = "MYEMAILID"
toaddr = "TOADDRESS" 
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Please find the attachment"
body = "HI" 
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain')) 
filename = "student.xlsx"
dt = str(datetime.datetime.now())
attachment = open("C:\\Users\\prashanth\\Desktop\\student.xlsx", "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename) 
msg.attach(part) 
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "Password")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: for what it's worth, YYYYMMDD is a better naming convention for files as sorting them gets the correct chronological order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.rename()` to rename a file, and `os.remove()` to remove a file. And to get the desired date format you can use `strftime()`, for example:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime
date_now = datetime.now().strftime('%m%d%Y')
file_one = "C:\\Users\\prashanth\\Desktop\\student.xlsx"
file_two = 'C:\\Users\\prashanth\\Desktop\\student_{}.xlsx'.format(date_now)
os.rename(file_one, file_two)
# send your email and attach the file
# and once you're done:
os.remove(file_two)
```

EDIT:

You need to `close()` the file before renaming or removing it, or better yet use `with-statement` to open the file and auto close it when you're done, for example:

```
attachment = open(file, "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
attachment.close()
```

or

```
with open(file, "rb") as attachment:
    part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
    part.set_payload((attachment).read())
```

Comment: Email is sent but am not able to remove the file :(Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\prashanth\Desktop\Phython program\gmail1.py", line 33, in <module>
    os.remove(file_two)
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\\Users\\prashanth\\Desktop\\student_08152017.xlsx'

Comment: That is because you `open()` the file and didn't `close()` it, so you either use `close()` after reading the file or you can open the file using `with open(file) as attachment:`

Comment: Check the edited answer

Comment: It worked thanks a lot !! but the file which was sent was not renamed to date format and i used .format(date_now) in the following line and it worked ! filename = "student_{}.xlsx".format(date_now)

Comment: I thought you were referring to file_two when attaching, missed `filename=` line. In that case you don't need to `os.rename()` in the first place, `filename = "student_{}.xlsx".format(date_now)` would be enough

Comment: thats great !! Thank u all so much :)

Comment: Glad to help :-)