# windows file directory path in Python

Tags: python-3.x, email

Can anyone please help me, I'm a newbie, I have a bit of code which I'm working on and I'm struggling with the file directory path. I have found other examples and tried them as shown below. The Python code is to email out a file called 'myfile.txt' form the folder `'F:\D\OneDrive\Python\Spyder\test'`.

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

#sender's address 
fromaddr = "username@gmail.com"
#receiptent's email address
toaddr = "username2@gmail.com"

msg = MIMEMultipart()

msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Python test"

body = "Did it work Sam?"

msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain'))

filename = "myfile.txt"
attachment = open("F:\D\OneDrive\Python\Spyder\test", "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename)

msg.attach(part)

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "password")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```

And I get this error -

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:         
  b'F:\\D\\OneDrive\\Python\\Spyder\\test'
```

If I change the line to -

```
attachment = open("F:\D\OneDrive\Python\Spyder\test\", "rb")
```

I get -

```
attachment = open("F:\D\OneDrive\Python\Spyder\test\", "rb")
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

If I change the line to -

```
attachment = open("F:\\D\\OneDrive\\Python\\Spyder\\test\\", "rb")
```

I get -

```
attachment = open("F:\\D\\OneDrive\\Python\\Spyder\\test\\", "rb")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:         
  'F:\\D\\OneDrive\\Python\\Spyder\\test\\'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you work in Windows you must use windows path format. Method `open` with `'rb'` parameters read `file` in byte mode if file is exist. You try read the directory!?

> attachment = open('F:\\D\\OneDrive\\Python\\Spyder\\test\\myfile.txt", "rb")

equal

> attachment = open(r'F:\D\OneDrive\Python\Spyder\test\myfile.txt', 'rb')

Comment: I can see what you mean and I tried them with and without the file name, but both gave me the error - SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal. Thanks anyhow

Comment: ^ Quoting issue here; fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

This represents the path correctly, but fails to provide a *file* name, because the trailing `\` means a directory.

```
attachment = open("F:\\D\\OneDrive\\Python\\Spyder\\test\\myfile.txt", "rb")
```

What you likely want is

```
# Note the r and the lack of a trailing slash.
attachment = open(r"F:\D\OneDrive\Python\Spyder\test\myfile.txt", "rb")
```

Comment: Its making more sense, but I get this error with your solution - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'F:\\D\\OneDrive\\Python\\Spyder\\test'   Thanks anyhow

Comment: Is this the real path to your file? After re-reading the question, I understood that it's only the path part, and the file is `myfile.txt`. I'm updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have found different code here and this works. Still can't work out why the original code does not work -
**[python program to rename the file with current date in MMDDYYY format and send email with attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45690763/python-program-to-rename-the-file-with-current-date-in-mmddyyy-format-and-send-e)**

Fixed code -

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders
fromaddr = "username@gmail.com"
toaddr = "username2@gmail.com" 
msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Please find the attachment"
body = "HI" 
msg.attach(MIMEText(body, 'plain')) 
filename = "myfile.txt"
#dt = str(datetime.datetime.now())
attachment = open("F:\\D\\OneDrive\\Python\\Spyder\\myfile.txt", "rb")
part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload((attachment).read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename= %s" % filename) 
msg.attach(part) 
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "password")
text = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddr, text)
server.quit()
```